# Generalize function to fold both elements with one higher-kinded type and with two nested types?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, composition, higher-kinded-types

I have next two elements:

```
x :: Maybe t
y :: [(String, t)]
```

And I have a function:

```
foo :: t -> a
```

How can I implement polymorphic function that can work both on `x` and `y` with `foo` to collect results in list? More specifically, I need to put something instead of `???` here:

```
mapToList :: ??? => (t -> a) -> ??? t -> [a]
```

And I want to call with less boilerplate possible, most closest option to this is preferable:

```
mapToList foo x
mapToList foo y
```

Something naive like this doesn't work :(

```
mapToList :: Foldable f => (t -> a) -> f t -> [a]
mapToList extractor = map extractor . toList

mapToList @Maybe             foo x
mapToList @([] ((,) String)) foo y
```

I was looking at [`Compose`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.21/base-4.9.1.0/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) but didn't manage to figure out how to apply it to my problem in nice simple way. I can use `Compose` to generalize **somehow** but my solution is not satisfactory. I can always use `map` for lists and just `maybe [] foo` on `Maybe`'s. But I wonder, is there nice way to generalize both use cases?

Comment: I think `mapToList foo (Compose y)` will work with your `mapToList` definition, if that's reasonable. `Compose y` would have type `Compose [] ((,) String) t`.

Comment: I like your solution with `Compose` more. Probably it's the least possible boilerplate I can imagine with general approach. But can it be done in reverse way? For example, mostly I have lists and only few `Maybe`'s. Can I somehow flatten or ignore types to specify type only for `Maybe`?

Comment: You could use `mapToList f = concatMap (map f . toList)` with type `mapToList :: (Foldable f) => (t -> a) -> [f t] -> [a]` and wrap your `Maybe` values in `[]`. Or you could use `(Foldable fo,Foldable fi) => fo (fi t)` and an extra `toList` call and wrap it in any `Foldable` (`Identity`, perhaps). I would probably prefer the list version unless the generality was truly needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this helps at all since it's just shifting the boilerplate away from the call site, but:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances,FunctionalDependencies,RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Functor.Compose (Compose(Compose))
import Data.Foldable

class AsFoldable x a | x -> a where
  withFoldable :: (forall f. (Foldable f) => f a -> b) -> x -> b

instance AsFoldable [(String,a)] a where
  withFoldable f = f . Compose

instance AsFoldable (Maybe a) a where
  withFoldable = id

x :: Maybe Int
x = Just 3

y :: [(String,Int)]
y = [("A",5),("B",6)]

mapToList :: (AsFoldable x t) => (t -> a) -> x -> [a]
mapToList f = withFoldable (map f . toList)

main = do
  print $ mapToList (+1) x
  print $ mapToList (+1) y
```